# How to start and stop saving video frames according to a trigger with OpenCV VideoWriter

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, ffmpeg, rtsp

I am building an app that records frames from IP camera through RTSP.

My engine is in charge to save a video in mp4 with Opencv VideoWriter working well.
What I am looking for is to create a startRecord and a stopRecord class method that will respectively start and stop recording according to a trigger (it could be an argument that I pass to the thread).
Is anyone know what the best way to do that kind of stuff?

Here is my class:

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2
import time
import multiprocessing
import threading
class RTSPVideoWriterObject(object):
    def __init__(self, src=0):
        # Create a VideoCapture object
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src)

        # Start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

    def update(self):
        # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()

    def endRecord(self):
        self.capture.release()
        self.output_video.release()
        exit(1)

    def startRecord(self,endRec):

        self.frame_width = int(self.capture.get(3))
        self.frame_height = int(self.capture.get(4))
        self.codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
        self.output_video = cv2.VideoWriter('fileOutput.mp4', self.codec, 30, (self.frame_width, self.frame_height))
        while True:          
            try:
                self.output_video.write(self.frame)
                if endRec:
                    self.endRecord()
            except AttributeError:
                pass




if __name__ == '__main__':

    rtsp_stream_link = 'rtsp://foo:192.5545....'
    video_stream_widget = RTSPVideoWriterObject(rtsp_stream_link)

    stop_threads = False
    t1 = threading.Thread(target = video_stream_widget.startRecord, args =[stop_threads]) 
    t1.start() 
    time.sleep(15)
    stop_threads = True
```

As you can see in the main I reading frames and store them in a separate thread. Then I am starting to record (record method is with an infinite loop so blocking) and then after 15 sec, I am trying to pass a 'stop_record' argument to stop recording properly.

A part of the code comes from [Storing RTSP stream as video file with OpenCV VideoWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55141315/storing-rtsp-stream-as-video-file-with-opencv-videowriter)

Is someone have an idea?
I read a lot that OpenCV can be very tricky for multithreading

N.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing arguments to the thread, use a internal flag  in the class to determine when to start/stop recording. The trigger could be as simple as pressing the spacebar to start/stop recording. When the spacebar is pressed it will switch an internal variable, say `self.record` to `True` to start recording and `False` to stop recording. Specifically, to check when the spacebar is pressed, you can check if the returned key value from `cv2.waitKey()` is `32`. If you want the trigger based on any other key, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59364385/pausing-and-restarting-a-video-in-python/59365045) to determine the key code. Here's a quick example to start/stop recording a video using the spacebar:

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2

class RTSPVideoWriterObject(object):
    def __init__(self, src=0):
        # Create a VideoCapture object
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
        self.record = True

        # Default resolutions of the frame are obtained (system dependent)
        self.frame_width = int(self.capture.get(3))
        self.frame_height = int(self.capture.get(4))

        # Set up codec and output video settings
        self.codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
        self.output_video = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', self.codec, 30, (self.frame_width, self.frame_height))

        # Start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

    def update(self):
        # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()

    def show_frame(self):
        # Display frames in main program
        if self.status:
            cv2.imshow('frame', self.frame)
            if self.record:
                self.save_frame()

        # Press Q on keyboard to stop recording
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            self.capture.release()
            self.output_video.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            exit(1)
        # Press spacebar to start/stop recording
        elif key == 32:
            if self.record:
                self.record = False
                print('Stop recording')
            else:
                self.record = True
                print('Start recording')

    def save_frame(self):
        # Save obtained frame into video output file
        self.output_video.write(self.frame)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rtsp_stream_link = 'Your stream link!'
    video_stream_widget = RTSPVideoWriterObject(rtsp_stream_link)
    while True:
        try:
            video_stream_widget.show_frame()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a global variable inside the class, for your case endRec.